# How to display an image from a pipe stream in nodejs to an img tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

We have this code that pipes an image stored in MongoDB using GridFS

```
exports.getOneVerificationImageByFilename = async (req, res, next) => {
  const image = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.image });
  try {
    const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(image.filename);
    readStream.on("error", function (err) {
      res.send("No image found with that title");
    });
    res.contentType("image/png");
    readStream.pipe(res);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

Im using `react` and I need to display this in an `<img/>` tag. This is how I called this endpoint

```
const getImage = async filename => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/image/${filename}`);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
}
```

Since the endpoint doesn't return any `res`, the `response` is empty. I then read about it that chunks of the data is being streamed. I found someone using this kind of syntax:

```
<img src="<%= url %>" />
```

However I dont understand it. I need to display the streamed chunks in an img tag

Answer (score 2):

My answer might be late but this is what worked for me.
Actually from browser, you must use [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) to access and manage streams of data received from your server side. Do not use axios, instead, use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) that exposes the response as a readable stream.

Here, you will have 3 functions :
**blobToBase64(blob)** converts a blob to base64 image. **readImageFromStream(requestBody)** will take a fetch request response body as parameter, read the streams received from the server and then return a base64 image

```
function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}



const readImageFromStream = async (fetchRequestResultBody) => {
      const reader = fetchRequestResultBody.getReader();
    
      const stream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
          return pump();
          // The following function handles each data chunk
          function pump() {
            // "done" is a Boolean and value a "Uint8Array"
            return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
              // If there is no more data to read
              if (done) {
                console.log("done", done);
                controller.close();
                return;
              }
              // Get the data and send it to the browser via the controller
              controller.enqueue(value);
              return pump();
            });
          }
        },
      });
    
      const response = new Response(stream);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      // const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const base64 = await blobToBase64(blob);
    
      return base64;
    };

(async () => {
  const requestedData = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3001/v2/medias/63270d49e260c93f70f527a0/featuredImage"
  );
  console.log(await readImageFromStream(requestedData.body));
})();
```